# A integral inequality

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

> Let $g\in C_0^\infty((-1,1))$.Prove $\forall t\in (-1,1)$,$${g^4}\left( t \right) \le 16\int_{ - 1}^1 {\left( {{{\left| {g'\left( s \right)} \right|}^2} - \frac{{{g^2}\left( s \right)}}{{4{{\left( {1 - \left| s \right|} \right)}^2}}}} \right)ds}  \cdot \int_{ - 1}^1 {{{\left| {g\left( s \right)} \right|}^2}ds} .$$

This is a unusual integral inequality, I have tyied Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but have no use.